# Calculating mean and standard deviation in java

Tags: java, standard-deviation

I'm not having problems with calculating the mean, but my standard deviation keeps coming out a little off. I'm stumped.
For the standard deviation, i use a for loop to go back through the array I filled with the user prompted values and subtract the mean from each value, then square it. Then one more for loop to sum them all together, divide by the number of values, and then square root it. What am i getting wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment4 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Please enter the number of items:"); // PROMPTS USER FOR # OF ITEMS
        double size = scan.nextDouble();

        double meanSum = 0;
        double deviationSum = 0;
        double array[] = new double [(int) size];


        System.out.println("Please enter the items");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                 array[i]= scan.nextDouble();
            }


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                meanSum += array[i];
            }

        double mean = ((meanSum / size));
        System.out.println("The mean is: " + mean);




        //STANDARD DEVIATION CALCULATION
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                array[i] = (Math.pow((array[i] - mean), 2));
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            deviationSum += array[i];
        }

        double variance = ((deviationSum / size));

        double standardDeviation = Math.sqrt(variance);
        System.out.println("The standard deviation is: " + standardDeviation);

    }

}
```

Comment: `What am i getting wrong?` What are you comparing against? Does it use [Bessel's Corresction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) eg`n-1`? See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-n-1-in-calculating-population-variance and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/intuitive-explanation-for-dividing-by-n-1-when-calculating-standard-deviation

Comment: Ah! dividing by n-1 fixed it. thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon what you are comparing your answer against, it may use a correction, such as [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction). In other words, rather than divide by `size`, divide by `size-1`. Also see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/intuitive-explanation-for-dividing-by-n-1-when-calculating-standard-deviation) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-n-1-in-calculating-population-variance)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare your answer to what DescriptiveStatistics outputs (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html)

You just call the `.addValue(double)` function, and at the end call the functions to return mean and standard deviation